# CloudTrail is obfuscating some fields in the Event records, how do I disable that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudtrail

Toying around with the AWS CodeTrail dashboard and investigating e.g. who disabled or deleted a user, I frequently see crucial fields in the Event record obfuscated and the contents replaced with asterisks. For example here:

```
{
  "eventVersion": "1.05",
  "userIdentity": {
    "type": "IAMUser",
    "principalId": "AIDACKCEVSQ6C2EXAMPLE",
    "arn": "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:user/Alice",
    "accountId": "444455556666",
    "accessKeyId": "AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE",
    "userName": "Alice",
    "sessionContext": {
      "sessionIssuer": {
          "type": "Role",
          "principalId": "AIDACKCEVSQ6C2EXAMPLE",
          "arn": "arn:aws:iam::444455556666:role/service-role/mylambda-role-agr9xeqt",
          "accountId": "444455556666",
          "userName": "mylambda-role-agr9xeqt"
      },
      "webIdFederationData": {},
      "attributes": {
          "mfaAuthenticated": "false",
          "creationDate": "2020-06-16T14:00:45Z"
      }
    }
  },
  "eventSource": "cognito-idp.amazonaws.com",
  "eventName": "AdminDisableUser",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
  "sourceIPAddress": "82.95.39.57",
  "userAgent": "aws-sdk-nodejs/2.631.0 linux/v12.16.3 exec-env/AWS_Lambda_nodejs12.x promise",
  "requestParameters": {
    "userPoolId": "myPool",
    "username": "******"
  },
  "responseElements": null,
  "requestID": "17daa5e6-8646-8762-a619-1e61e70cc6d3",
  "eventID": "9fd9b856-3467-4e67-8165-78cbe298792d",
  "eventType": "AwsApiCall"
}
```

As you can see, `"username"` within `"requestParameters"` has been replaced by `"******"` in the event record of an **AdminDisableUser** call, while `"userPoolId"` gives the actual data. There are other things that might be obfuscated like this automatically in the `"requestParameters"`. For example `"userAttributes"` for event records of **AdminUpdateUserAttributes**.

I am assuming that this behaviour is due to requirements by the AWS Well-Architected-Framework, that certain sensitive data is being obfuscated by default because it could be a security risk. Or is maybe my role or account being limited in some way so that I don't have access to this information?

In any case, assuming that I have complete and unlimited priviledges for the account, how can I enable that these fields in the event records are not obfuscated like that in CloudTrail but that it should show me the actual real data for the API call instead?

Answer (score 0):

There are [cases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-event-reference-user-identity.html) where CloudTrail obfuscates the username if the username could not be proven to be valid, and this is because of the high incidence of people typing passwords into username fields. If that's the case here, then you can't get access to the actual username.

Comment: In this case, the usernames were valid, though. I just reproduced generating such a log message. You can do, too: Disable a user in the web console for the Cognito service (maybe you need to create an additional user first), then enable him again. Wait until the CloudTrails logs are updated, examine the Event record.